# OpenJFX 11 - javafxpackager Binary CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx, openjfx, openjdk-11

It seems like the JavaFXpackager isn't available in the openjdk/openjfx 11.

I want to create the binary CSS (BSS) using it.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javafxpackager.html
with the `-createbss` it was possible in the past.

In the OpenJFX mailing list, they posted something about `Filling the Packager gap`.
https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2018-September/022500.html

But this new tool cant create Binary CSS.

My question is:
Is there still a way to generate the binary css using OpenJFX 11 or is the whole thing not supported anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is a `jpackage` [tool](http://jdk.java.net/jpackage/) that is possibly being added to Java 14, I'm not aware that it is going to use `Css2Bin`.

In OpenJFX (11+), `Css2Bin` is still a tool used internally to convert the Modena CSS files into BSS. You can find it [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/css/parser/Css2Bin.java).

If you search the uses of this tool within OpenJFX, you will [find it](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/f595cc19dd6f1b22ea48ee6d0e99c7bd03e245e1/build.gradle#L2526) in the `build.gradle` file that is used to build JavaFX itself.

I'll paste the task, as it is relevant to see what it does:

```
def modulePath = "${project.sourceSets.main.java.outputDir}"
    modulePath += File.pathSeparator + "${rootProject.projectDir}/modules/javafx.graphics/build/classes/java/main"
    modulePath += File.pathSeparator + "${rootProject.projectDir}/modules/javafx.base/build/classes/java/main"
    processResources {
      doLast {
        def cssFiles = fileTree(dir: "$moduleDir/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin")
        cssFiles.include "**/*.css"
        cssFiles.each { css ->
            logger.info("converting CSS to BSS ${css}");

            javaexec {
                executable = JAVA
                workingDir = project.projectDir
                jvmArgs += patchModuleArgs
                jvmArgs += "--module-path=$modulePath"
                jvmArgs += "--add-modules=javafx.graphics"
                main = "com.sun.javafx.css.parser.Css2Bin"
                args css
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

As you can notice, basically a `java` command is called, with the JavaFX jars in the module path, to run the `Css2Bin::main` public method, which is just part of the `javafx.graphics` included module.

So nothing prevents you from doing exactly the same in your build process.

Assuming you are using Gradle, you can add a task that is executed before the `jar` task, something like this:

```
def java_home = hasProperty('org.gradle.java.home') ? 
      getProperty('org.gradle.java.home') : System.getenv('JAVA_HOME')

task css {
    if (java_home == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("java_home is not defined.")
    }
    def cssFiles = fileTree(dir: "$project.rootDir/src/main/resources/")
    cssFiles.include "**/*.css"
    cssFiles.each { css ->
        logger.info("converting CSS to BSS ${css}")
        doLast {
            exec {
                commandLine "${java_home}/bin/java",
                        "--module-path", sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.asPath,
                        "--add-modules", "javafx.graphics",
                        "com.sun.javafx.css.parser.Css2Bin", css
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Simply run:

```
./gradlew css
```

and it will convert all the css files in your resources to bss. Then you will probably need to filter out the css ones when doing the jar.

Same task can be run in a similar way from Maven or command line, of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer :) It's helping me a lot.

Comment: How the generated bss files could be automatically written directly to the build directory, without adding them to the resources directory?

Comment: `Css2Bin` allows a second argument with the file name (and path) of the output.

Comment: Ok, do you have some example of that?

Comment: No, just try it out. Better to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, here is what José meant with

> Same task can be run in a similar way from Maven [...]

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>css2bss</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.sun.javafx.css.parser.Css2Bin</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <arg>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/my-theme.css</arg>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Assuming that `javafx.graphics` is in your reactor's dependencies already.

Comment: This works thank you. How we add multiple files. Since I have a set of css files ?

Comment: I guess the only way is to add multiple `<execution>`s (each with a different id and different arguments).

Comment: I used alternative way. I have written utility  class loop this this main class and used my class in the plugin that get multiple arguments. It was success. Thank you